# How to 'Cat' multiple files and validate result C#

Tags: c#, bdd, specflow

I've written code where i've given a file path and an expected result. But how can i change the `var Path` so i enter multiple file names and expect multiple outputs in the `var expected`.

```
[Then(@"Transfer measure should be generated for (.*)")]
public void ValidateMeasurement(string lifecyclestatus)
{
    var Path = "irm_pww_xxx_xxx.csv.ovr";
    const string processFilePath = "/orabin/app//ff/actuals/";
    var actual = Common.LinuxCommandExecutor
                       .RunLinuxcommand($"cat {processFilePath} {Path}");

    var expected = "6677,6677_6677,3001,6";

    Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);

}
```

Comment: Isn't this a general Linux command question? I think you can just write "cat file1 file2 file3" and so on.

Comment: cat's man page is [here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cat.1.html)

Answer (score 2):

```
   .RunLinuxcommand($"cat {processFilePath}/* {Path}");
```

should do the trick. Putting wildcards into pathnames is called *globbing* in UNIX derivatives. It's handy because it sorts the filenames it matches in lexical order, so you always get the same set of files in the same order.

But `.../*` is a bit promiscuous, it will take all files in that directory. You might be better off with

```
   .RunLinuxcommand($"cat {processFilePath}/*.tstout {Path}");
```

or some appropriate extension for the files you hope to gather.

You can test globbing by saying `echo whatever/*.whatever` and you'll see the file names.